# Error 508 - many GET requests to non-existent paths

Tags: wordpress, performance, server, get

I am having a lot of trouble with exceeding the allocated resources on my shared web host.

I am exceeding both threads and memory on daily basis when I share a post on facebook (I am using wordpress).

I have checked the logs and I see that 6 of the 7 most popular requests are to files and paths that no longer exists on my server (at least I don't think so).

See below:

[image]

I have checked the source code of my pages and there is no trace of these paths. The plugins in question do not exists on my server (have searched both ftp and sql).

I am not even sure if these requests are even the root of my problems, but it seems strange to me. Especially as the requests are coming from hundreds of different, seemingly normal IPs.

I am going crazy, seeing my site down all the time.

Comment: Do you have any security plugins installed? It might help prevent requests to non-existent resources.

Comment: Can you recommend one in particular?

Comment: Here's a [list](http://resources.infosecinstitute.com/7-best-wordpress-security-plugins/) of plugins. This could help you decide which is best for your needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to me you have previously installed this [plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/user-submitted-posts/).

I have downloaded this plugin and check that plugin it is having all the files which are called on your server. Have you active this plugin before?

Check with databse is there any word like 'usp_options'.

This is a big comment due to that i posted it in the answer not in the comment.

Comment: I have had it installed in the past, I think. But now there is no trace of it at all on my ftp or in the database. A search for "usp_options" shows zero results. But it seems like my site is still making call to all the paths from the plugin. It's odd.

Comment: exactly i guess that plugin has some bad code which are still putted the cron or something like due to that this is happening we need to check with each file of that plugin and than i guess we can resolve the issue because this issue has come from that plugin only. Do one thing active another theme and check the results? after changing the theme does it resolved your issue?

Comment: Are you having cache enable on site?

Comment: Yeah I have cache, but I have tried searching the cache files as well, but the plugin or it's assets is nowhere to be found.

Comment: Flush all the cache and did you tried with switching your website to another  theme